# Updating one-to-many relationships without SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many, savechanges

When a call is made to the SaveChanges() method of an context, the relationships on the other side of the change are automatically updated.

For instance if I had a teacher mrX with a virtual ICollection of students including littleJohnny

```
mrX.Students.Remove(littleJohnny);
Debug.Assert(littleJohnny.Teacher!=null); //assert should pass
context.SaveChanges();
Debug.Assert(littleJohnny.Teacher==null); //assert should pass

mrX.Students.Add(littleJohnny);
context.SaveChanges();//revert to previous state

littleJohnny.Teacher=null;
Debug.Assert(mrX.Students.Contains(littleJohnny)); //assert should pass
context.SaveChanges();
Debug.Assert(!mrX.Students.Contains(littleJohnny)); //assert should pass
```

1. Is there any way to update such relationships without saving the data to the database in Entity Framework 4.3 and 5.0 ?
2. In a different scenario, If I have a ViewModel which maps to the above entities, is there a simple way I can copy this EF behavior -> that is, track the relationships and update the relationships on calling a method?

Comment: Couple of Questions: 1. ARe you using EF Code-first? 2. When you ViewModel, are you talking WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: Sorry - should have specified, Yes I am using code first. As for view model I predominantly use mvvm and WPF, but really b view model I mean something mapped across from the entities, such as using Automapper onto a POCO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`

if that doesn't work then your related entities have not been initialised correctly